# How to set up a tag to record clicks of sort by categories list of a product page

Tags: google-tag-manager

I am very new to gtm and trying to set up a tag that can record clicks of the sort by categories of all product pages.

Each category page has the sort by (like any other website), it for example has the options:

1. Price high to low
2. Price low to high
3. Date added
4. Name a-z
5. Name z-a

What I am trying to do is to be able track how many people click on those individual sort by categories? I am not sure how to go about this, need guidance.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to identify the click as it happens and then send the information to GA. So you need this two blocks in GTM: an universal analytics tag as "event" and a trigger which listens for clicks.

If you don't know CSS selectors the most easy way to find the right values for the trigger is by try and error. Activate the GTM debug mode and navigate to your list.
Now click on the sorting feature, does a click appears in the GTM debug console (the one you see in the lower part of your page)? If no click appears you need to activate at least one trigger which simply listens for any clicks that happen on your page. Now when you see clicks in your GTM debug console: select the click (in "summary" tab of gtm debug console) which appeared when you sorted. Now when the click is selected in summary the "variables" tab will show you all values within your defined variables.

All click variables should be activated in GTM. Then you can see what information is hold in them, when the user sorts.

As you now know the values of your variables when the sort action appears, you should use this information to create a trigger (something like: click element contains "xyz") and an universal analytics event which will send event category, action and label (one of these should contain information on click element) to Google Analytics as soon as your trigger is activated.

Comment: Thanks. Makes sense, will try that today and hopefully all works.

Comment: Hey, so the tag records the clicks now but in google analytics for some reason each cateogry is shows and when you click in it then it shows the detailed clicks on that category. I was expecting to see the tag name within which the 5 categories show with the click details. Any ideas?